# Need SQL JOIN statement assistance

Tags: sql, oracle

I am creating a report that needs to list both Primary Person Id and Alternate Person ID. But it also needs to show both Primary Person IDs contact information and Alternates. Report I've created right now only lists out Primary Person ID's contact information, but shows the Alternates ID number. Can someone assist me in fixing my sql so both Primary and Alternates contact information is listed and not just the Primary's. The sql I have is below.

```
            SELECT "ORG_ACCOUNT".ACCOUNT_NUMBER AS "Account Number",
                   "ORG_PERSON".ADDRESS_2 AS "Address",
                   "ORG_ACCOUNT".DODAAC AS "Dodaac",
                   "ORG_DODAAC".DRA AS "Dra",
                   "ORG_PERSON".EMAIL AS "Email",
                   "ORG_PERSON".FIRST_NAME AS "First Name",
                   "ORG_PERSON".LAST_NAME AS "Last Name",
                   "ORG_PERSON".LAST_TRAIN_DATE AS "Last Train Date",
                   "ORG_PERSON".MIDDLE_NAME AS "Middle Name",
                   "ORG_ALT_ACCOUNT_CUST".PERSON_ID AS "Alt Person Id",
                   "ORG_ORG".ORG_NAME AS "Org Name",
                   "ORG_ACCOUNT".PERSON_ID AS "Person Id",
                   "ORG_PERSON".PHONE_COM AS "Phone Com",
                   "ORG_PERSON".PHONE_DSN AS "Phone Dsn",
                   "ORG_PERSON".RANK AS "Rank"
           FROM "ORG"."ORG_ACCOUNT" "ORG_ACCOUNT",
                "ORG"."ORG_DODAAC" "ORG_DODAAC",
                "ORG"."ORG_ORG" "ORG_ORG",
                "ORG"."ORG_PERSON" "ORG_PERSON"
                "ORG"."ORG_ALT_ACCOUNT_CUST" "ORG_ALT_ACCOUNT_CUST"
           WHERE ( ( "ORG_PERSON".PERSON_ID(+) = ORG_ALT_ACCOUNT_CUST".PERSON_ID )
             AND   ( "ORG_ORG".ORG_ID = "ORG_ACCOUNT".ORG_ID ) 
             AND   ( "ORG_PERSON".PERSON_ID = "ORG_ACCOUNT".PERSON_ID )
             AND   ( "ORG_ALT_ACCOUNT_CUST".PERSON_ID = "ORG_ACCOUNT".PERSON_ID )
             AND   ( "ORG_DODAAC".DODAAC = "ORG_ACCOUNT".DODAAC ) ) 
             AND   ( UPPER("ORG_ACCOUNT".DODAAC) LIKE UPPER(:DODAAC) 
             AND    "ORG_DODAAC".DRA IN ( :P_DRA_ENTRIES)
             AND     UPPER("ORG_ACCOUNT".DODAAC_COMMODITY) = UPPER('A') )
           ORDER BY "ORG_DODAAC".DRA ASC, "ORG_ACCOUNT".ACCOUNT_NUMBER ASC, "ORG_PERSON".LAST_NAME ASC
```

Comment: You sure you are using MySQL and not SQL server (MSSQL), Oracle or PostgreSQL? MySQL normally does not support double qoutes for identifiers like database name, table name and columns unless you configure the sql_mode `ANSI_QUOTES` .. I also advice you to read [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) and provide text formatted example data and matching expected text formatted results

Comment: `(+)` is `Oracle` syntax only i didn't notice it before i changed the tags from MySQL to Oracle.. the (+) can be used to use a LEFT or RIGHT join it's a extension by Oracle to support LEFT and RIGHT JOIN 's with the old ANSI comma JOIN syntax which you should **not** be using anymore. You should be using proper JOIN syntax like `table1 INNER JOIN table ON ...` or `table1 RIGHT|LEFT JOIN table ON ...`

Comment: We are using oracle in our work place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to join a table twice, like you do here with ORG_PERSON, you need to list it twice in the FROM clause (with different aliases).

```
SELECT ORG_ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER AS "Account Number",
                   ORG_PERSON.ADDRESS_2 AS "Address",
                   ORG_ACCOUNT.DODAAC AS "Dodaac",
                   ORG_DODAAC.DRA AS "Dra",
                   ORG_PERSON.EMAIL AS "Email",
                   ORG_PERSON.FIRST_NAME AS "First Name",
                   ORG_PERSON.LAST_NAME AS "Last Name",
                   ORG_PERSON.LAST_TRAIN_DATE AS "Last Train Date",
                   ORG_PERSON.MIDDLE_NAME AS "Middle Name",
                   ORG_ALT_ACCOUNT_CUST.PERSON_ID AS "Alt Person Id",
                   ORG_ORG.ORG_NAME AS "Org Name",
                   ORG_ACCOUNT.PERSON_ID AS "Person Id",
                   ORG_PERSON.PHONE_COM AS "Phone Com",
                   ORG_PERSON.PHONE_DSN AS "Phone Dsn",
                   ORG_PERSON.RANK AS "Rank",
                   alt_person.address_2 as "Alt Address",
                   alt_person.email as "Alt Email",
                   alt_person.first_name as "Alt First Name",
                   alt_person.last_name as "Alt Last Name",
                   alt_person.phone_com as "Alt Phone"
           FROM "ORG".ORG_ACCOUNT ORG_ACCOUNT,
                "ORG".ORG_DODAAC ORG_DODAAC,
                "ORG".ORG_ORG ORG_ORG,
                "ORG".ORG_PERSON ORG_PERSON
                "ORG".ORG_ALT_ACCOUNT_CUST ORG_ALT_ACCOUNT_CUST,
                "ORG".ORG_PERSON alt_person
           WHERE ( ( alt_person.PERSON_ID(+) = ORG_ALT_ACCOUNT_CUST.PERSON_ID )
             AND   ( ORG_ORG.ORG_ID = ORG_ACCOUNT.ORG_ID ) 
             AND   ( ORG_PERSON.PERSON_ID = ORG_ACCOUNT.PERSON_ID )
             AND   ( ORG_ALT_ACCOUNT_CUST.PERSON_ID = ORG_ACCOUNT.PERSON_ID )
             AND   ( ORG_DODAAC.DODAAC = ORG_ACCOUNT.DODAAC ) ) 
             AND   ( UPPER(ORG_ACCOUNT.DODAAC) LIKE UPPER(:DODAAC) 
             AND    ORG_DODAAC.DRA IN ( :P_DRA_ENTRIES)
             AND     UPPER(ORG_ACCOUNT.DODAAC_COMMODITY) = UPPER('A') )
           ORDER BY ORG_DODAAC.DRA ASC, ORG_ACCOUNT.ACCOUNT_NUMBER ASC, ORG_PERSON.LAST_NAME ASC
```

Some style notes: I removed the double quotes from your table names and aliases because they're annoying and unnecessary. But I left your query in the old proprietary Oracle join syntax instead of ANSI joins, since I know a lot of workplaces still use it as an internal coding standard. I left my changes in lowercase so they'd be easy to see.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked. I will definitely take your advice. Again thank you so much for the help!